# start ssh-agent in remote ssh session

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I connect to a server that runs xubuntu and start ssh-agent there. Then I execute ssh-add on the remote server and run rysnc commands that would require to enter the passwort mutliple times.

With my solution I only have to enter it one time. But how can I start the ssh-agent permanentely? I want to reuse it over multiple ssh sessions.

My solution so far:

```
ssh myhost 'eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add;'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use agent-forwarding in ssh: `-A` switch. Basically, it will create the agent on your host and when you connect to `myhost`, you will have your agent in all your sessions and you will not be prompted for password again.

Basically agent should be started automatically with your session, so all you need to do is to add your keys locally and then connect to remote hosts with `-A` switch.

It is impossible to have running ssh-agent permanently, since it is running under your session. Basically if you don't close the first session, there is some way to connect to it, but it is certainly not the thing you want to do